# Is it OK to ask a question whose answer we already know?

Tags: discussion, questions, self-answer

Recently, a user has asked a [question](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/4805/sorting-as-a-linear-program) whose answer he pointed out in a comment. One of the moderators voiced his opinion that "[i]t is fine to post interesting material even if you know the answer. The conventional way to do so is to answer your own question with an (elaborate) take (instead of posting a links to some document, which may break)." Is this official policy? What do others think?

Comment: Yes, it is fine. Check the [FAQ]. Also see [this](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

Comment: One point is that the OP should give other people a chance of answering the question.

Comment: @DaveClarke [Not even that is true (anymore).](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/).

Comment: @DaveClarke Anyone can answer any non-closed question, regardless of whether the asker has answered it. If you meant that the asker should wait to post his answer, then no, this is impolite: it would mean that others might have to redo the asker's work. This is now officially promoted via a [user interface feature](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) that lets you post your answer at the same time as the question.

Comment: Strange, I must say. Will I play ball? Yes, I will. (See what I did there?)

Comment: see also [policy on stocking beta with easy questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/35/policy-on-stocking-the-beta-with-easy-questions)

Comment: @vzn That phase is long past, and even then we concluded not to do overly easy questions on purpose. So I'm not sure how that discussion is relevant to this one. ("knowing the answer" != "easy")

Comment: I'm wondering if this approach (posting question and answering) is a good way to handle the "check-my-proof" style questions. This way instead of posting a question and partial (or full) solution _in_ the questions. The user may post the question and attempt separately.

Comment: @Nicholas, I think that is a very good idea. I suggest that you post it as a new meta-discussion.

Answer (score 7):

It is [official policy](https://cs.stackexchange.com/faq) (as stated in the FAQ of every Stack Exchange site) that

> It’s also OK to [ask and answer your own question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/).

If you've done some research, thinking or experimentation to solve a problem, and there is a Stack Exchange site where you could have formulated your problem as a question, then you're encouraged to ask the question, and contribute your work in the form of an answer. This allows everyone to benefit from your work. It may also allow you to receive better or complementary answers. Everybody wins.

Comment: For reference, [the latest SE blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/05/encyclopedia-stack-exchange/) on the topic, clearly encouraging to post your answer *immediately*.